# How to generate 4 random non-repeating numbers from 0-9?

Tags: javascript, random

I want to get a random digit from 0-9 and have it popped so it doesn't get repeated but I find that after the the second number is pushed it doesn't have it's number popped. Instead, some other number not yet selected is popped giving room for a repeat.

```js
var yourNum = [],
  oppNum = [],
  choose = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function chooseRandomNumber() {
  return choose[Math.floor(Math.random() * choose.length)];
}

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  if (i === 0) {
    yourNum.push(chooseRandomNumber());
    if (yourNum[yourNum.length - 1] === 9) {
      choose.pop();
    } else {
      choose.splice(yourNum[0], 1);
    }
  } else if (i === 1) {
    yourNum.push(chooseRandomNumber());
    if (yourNum[yourNum.length - 1] === 9) {
      choose.pop();
    } else {
      choose.splice(yourNum[1], 1);
    }
  } else if (i === 2) {
    yourNum.push(chooseRandomNumber());
    if (yourNum[yourNum.length - 1] === 9) {
      choose.pop();
    } else {
      choose.splice(yourNum[2], 1);
    }
  } else if (i === 3) {
    yourNum.push(chooseRandomNumber());
    if (yourNum[yourNum.length - 1] === 9) {
      choose.pop();
    } else {
      choose.splice(yourNum[3], 1);
    }
  }
}

console.log(choose);
console.log(yourNum);
```

Comment: please add a possible result as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Edit

Takes four unique numbers out of the `choose` array. Is that what you're after?

```js
var yourNum = [],
  oppNum = [],
  choose = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function chooseRandomNumber() {
  return choose[Math.floor(Math.random() * choose.length)];
}

var rand;
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  rand = chooseRandomNumber();
  yourNum.push(rand);
  choose.splice(choose.indexOf(rand), 1);
}

console.log(choose);
console.log(yourNum);
```

Old approach:

```js
var start = 0, end = 9;

function generate(count) {
  var nums = [],
    random;

  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    while (!random || nums.indexOf(random) !== -1) {
      random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (end + 1)) + start;
    }

    nums.push(random);
  }
  
  return nums;
}

console.log(
  generate(4)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getRand(min, max, result) {
  result = result || [];
  
  if(result.length == 4) {
    return result;
  }
  
  var rand =  Math.floor(Math.random()*max) + min;
  
  if(result.indexOf(rand) === -1) {
    result.push(rand);
  }
  return getRand(min, max, result);
}

var result = getRand(1,9);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your whole approach is way to complicated and unperformant.

A better approach:

```js
//first we need a shuffle function
function shuffle(array){
    for(var i = array.length, j, tmp; i--; ){
        j = 0|(Math.random() * i);
        tmp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[i];
        array[i] = tmp;
    }
    return array;
}

//now let's define a sequence of possible values
var numset = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

//shuffle the sequence and take the first 4 values 
var fourRandomValues = shuffle(numset).slice(0,4);
console.log("four random values: " + fourRandomValues);

//doing this multiple times:
for(var values = []; values.length < 10;){
    //shuffle again, and take the values that are now at the beginning of this sequence
    values.push( shuffle(numset).slice(0,4) );
}
console.log("more random values: \n" + values.join("\n"));
```

**Edit:**

to address holi-java's approach by implementing sort of an Iterator, I'll add a way to do this with ES6 Iterators/Generators

Since Generators can be unlimited sequences we need to account for that. We do that by buffering a limited amount of values and returning them randomly; basically a shifiting frame of shuffled values.

```js
function *shuffled(iterable, bufferSize = 256){
    var buffer, numValues = 0, randomIndex;
    if(Array.isArray(iterable) && iterable.length <= bufferSize){
        //an optimization for (small) Arrays:
        buffer = iterable.slice();
        numValues = iterable.length;
    }else{
        buffer = Array( bufferSize )
        for(var value of iterable){
            //push value from the iterable to the buffer
            buffer[numValues++] = value;
            
            //buffer is full, yield a random value
            if(numValues === bufferSize){
                //choose a random value from the buffer
                randomIndex = 0|(Math.random() * (numValues-1));
                //yield it
                yield buffer[randomIndex];
                
                //overwrite the value with the last index 
                //that's cheaper than pop() and splice()
                buffer[randomIndex] = buffer[--numValues];
            }
        }
    }
    //iterable doesn't provide any more values
    //flush the buffer in a random order
    while(numValues){
        randomIndex = 0|(Math.random() * (numValues-1));
        yield buffer[randomIndex];
        buffer[randomIndex] = buffer[--numValues];
    }
}

//every Array is a valid iterator
for(var v of shuffled([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])) 
    console.log(v);
```

That way we can shuffle a stream of values without first caching all the values in an array.

- pro:  memory efficient
- possible problem: if the buffer's to small the result doesn't feel random anymore since values that are generated late in the sequence simply can not be shifted entirely to the start. You see some noise but it doesn't feel random anymore.

now let's take a jump into potentially infinite sequences:

```js
// *shuffled again, for this snippet
function *shuffled(iterable, bufferSize = 256){
    var buffer, numValues = 0, randomIndex;
    if(Array.isArray(iterable) && iterable.length <= bufferSize){
        buffer = iterable.slice();
        numValues = iterable.length;
    }else{
        buffer = Array( bufferSize )
        for(var value of iterable){
            buffer[numValues++] = value;
            if(numValues === bufferSize){
                randomIndex = 0|(Math.random() * (numValues-1));
                yield buffer[randomIndex];
                buffer[randomIndex] = buffer[--numValues];
            }
        }
    }
    while(numValues){
        randomIndex = 0|(Math.random() * (numValues-1));
        yield buffer[randomIndex];
        buffer[randomIndex] = buffer[--numValues];
    }
}

//creates an infinite sequence of numbers
function *count(){
    for(var index = 0; true;)
        yield index++;
}

//like limits a iterator but for iterators
function *take(n, iterator){
    for(var value of iterator){
        if(n-- > 0) yield value;
        else break;
    }
}

//create an (infinite) counter and convert it into a generator of shuffled values
//with a bufferSize of 256 entries (play a bit with that value)
var shuffledSequence = shuffled(count(), 256);
//to convert that into an Array we take the first 1000 values generated from that generator
var array = [...take(1000, shuffledSequence)];
//and log it
console.log(array.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean like this below:

```
function next() {
function all() {
    return [].concat(Array(10).fill(null).map(function (_, index) {
        return index;
    }));
}
function random(start, end) {
    return parseInt(Math.random() * (end + 1 - start)) + start;
}
var self = this;

self.all = self.all && self.all.length && self.all || all().sort(function(){
    return random(-1, 1);
});
return self.all.shift();}
var results=Array(4).fill(null).map(next);
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

my be this is better for browser to run.

```js
var it = {
    next: function () {
        var self = this;
        self._all = self._all && self._all.length && self._all || self.shuffle(self.all());

        return self._all.shift();
    },
    all: function () {
        return [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    },
    random: function (start, end) {
        if (!end && end != 0) {
            end = start;
            start = 0;
        }
        return parseInt(Math.random() * (end + 1 - start)) + start;
    },
    shuffle: function (array) {
        var self = this;
        for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
            self.swap(array, i, self.random(i));
        }
        return array;
    },
    swap: function (array, i, j) {
        var tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = tmp;
    },
    reset: function () {
        this._all = null;
    }
};
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var results=[];
    for(var n=0;n<4;n++) results.push(it.next());
    console.log("retain:"+it._all + '>>generated:' + results);
    it.reset();
}
```

Comment: yes, this is better than Okmarq's approach, but this is such a bloated and complicated implementation. Instead of building a proprietary iterator take a look at [JS native Iterator or Generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) I'll update [my answer](/a/42455604/6567275) with an example in a moment.

Answer (score -1):

Demo:

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

var yourNums = [];
var choose = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  yourNums = yourNums.concat(choose.splice(getRandomInt(0, choose.length), 1))
}

console.log("yourNums is:")
console.log(yourNums);
console.log("===")
console.log("choose is:")
console.log(choose);
```